# Apache not working on port 8082

Tags: apache-2.2, port

I set up a site a while ago to work on port 8080, and copying the configuration, changing only the root directory and port, I expected to have another site served on port 8082, but it fails with: `Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.`

Here are all the relevant config files, I can post more if there is something missing.

```
sysadmin@cpms-hub:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default 
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/stocker/app/webroot
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
sysadmin@cpms-hub:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website 
<VirtualHost *:8082>

        ServerAdmin billy@itaccess.org

        DocumentRoot /var/www/website
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
sysadmin@cpms-hub:~$ ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  3 15:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May  9 16:12 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 May  9 16:12 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Oct  3 15:30 default -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Aug 15 23:41 hub -> ../sites-available/hub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Oct  3 15:32 website -> /etc/apache2/sites-available/website
sysadmin@cpms-hub:~$ ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-available/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  3 15:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May  9 16:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  257 Aug 15 23:18 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7469 Feb  7  2012 default-ssl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  170 Aug 15 23:30 hub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176 Oct  3 15:44 website
sysadmin@cpms-hub:~$
```

Comment: Did you include the port in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` if it's a debianesque system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set apache to listen on port 8082? You'll need to add an additional [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) statement in an appropriate configuration file.

```
Listen 8080 
Listen 8082
```